# @NamedQuery in Spring CrudRepository - SQLServerException: Invalid column name 'id'

Tags: sql-server, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I am calling a service that uses a @NamedQuery in a CrudRepository to return a domain object.  I'm seeing the error

```
2017-04-05 16:43:16.063  WARN 14240 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 207, SQL
State: S0001
2017-04-05 16:43:16.065 ERROR 14240 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Invalid column name
 'id'.
2017-04-05 16:43:16.076  INFO 14240 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer :

... 27 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid column name 'id'.
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:232) ~[mssql-jd
bc-6.1.0.jre8.jar!/:na]
```

I don't understand this error as there is no column 'id' in my database table.  Not sure what's going on

My table is

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tb_changes_reports_v2](
    [reportID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [global_checksum] [int] NULL,
    [specific_checksum] [int] NULL,
    [batch] [int] NULL,
    [pushed] [bit] NULL,
    [compare_date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [ver] [bigint] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

My @Entity looks like

```
@Entity(name = "ChangesReports")
@Table(name="tb_changes_reports_v2")
@NamedQuery(name = "ChangesReports.findByTheReportId", query = "from ChangesReports c where c.reportId = ?1")
public class ChangesReports extends AbstractPersistable<Long> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -452961221197917532L;

    @Column(name="reportID", unique = true)
    private Long reportId;

My @Repository looks like

@Repository
public interface ChangesReportsRepository extends CrudRepository<ChangesReports, Long>, ChangesReportsRepositoryCustom {

    ChangesReports findByTheReportId(Long reportId);
```

My service looks like

```
@Override
public ChangesReports findByTheReportId(Long reportId) {
    return changesReportsRepository.findByTheReportId(reportId);
}
```

I'm using these @Bean definitions to autowire my beans

```
   @Bean
public ChangesReportsServiceImpl changesReportsServiceImpl() {
        ChangesReportsServiceImpl changesReportsServiceImpl = new ChangesReportsServiceImpl();
        return changesReportsServiceImpl;
    }

    @Bean
    public ChangesReportsRepositoryImpl changesReportsRepository() {
        ChangesReportsRepositoryImpl changesReportsRepositoryImpl = new ChangesReportsRepositoryImpl();
        return changesReportsRepositoryImpl;
    }
```

Again not sure why I'm receiving 'Invalid column name 'id'.'  as there's no column named 'id'.  Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: What about AbstractPersistable? Does the class have Id column?

Comment: No there was not an id column.  Thank you - that was a very good hint - I added an id column and the problem was fixed.

Comment: @user619804 please post it as an answer so other users can find it more easily

Answer (score 0):

Fyi the answer to me was to alter my table so that it has an ID column which was required by AbstractPersistable interface

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tb_changes_reports_v2](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [reportID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [global_checksum] [int] NULL,
    [specific_checksum] [int] NULL,
    [batch] [int] NULL,
    [pushed] [bit] NULL,
    [compare_date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [ver] [bigint] NULL
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
            (
                [ID] ASC
            )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```